# Completely remove an application from backstack

Tags: android, android-activity

**The Task**

I am supposed to connect two application that I made in android . Lets call one of them A (with activities  A1 , A2, A3) and B (activities B1 ,B2 , B3) . A user would login from Application A ,and would be redirected to Application B . In Application B , the user might hop between activities . After he is done , he would press LOGOUT from Application B , and would be redirected to Application A . 
Upon doing this , I want the Application B to be cleared from the backstack .

**The Problem** 
Even though upon logout I am finishing all the activities from the stack , the application name B is still mentioned in the back stack .

**What I have achieved so far**
This is how I invoke the Application B from Application A

```
    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("appB", "appB.MainActivity"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra(ARG_G2G_ACCESS_TOKEN, mTokenResponse.getAccessToken());

                startActivity(intent);
```

Upon logout , this is how I call the application A again . Firstly I finish all the activities that are running in the Task . Then I do

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("appA", "appA.MainActivity"));
```

However even with the above the Application Application B is still mentioned in the Backstack. I would like that to be removed when B is launched from A.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try noHistory for B?

Comment: what about `finish();` ?

Comment: Set `noHistory` flag to `true` as suggested by Pankaj

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/3871491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the answer by Luke at the link below: 
[Close application and remove from recent apps/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166282/close-application-and-remove-from-recent-apps)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ExitActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"/>
enter code here
```

Then create a class ExitActivity.java:

```
public class ExitActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public static void exitApplication(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExitActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, You can add `finish ()`

or use `android:noHistory="true"`

**`finish ()`** : ***Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.***

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                .....
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                .........

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

You can visit here **[How to finish current activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000787/how-to-finish-current-activity-in-android)** .Hope this helps .