# How do I implement a Button that will return to "Home" after it is clicked?

Tags: java, android, button

I have created a "Button" in android studio to send emails. When I click it, it sends an email as intended, but does not then return to the "Home" activity.

Comment: Try using `intent` to reopen your home activity after sending email.

Comment: Just finish() the activity after sending the email if its an activity which is opened by home activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish();` method, but it's not recommended.

**See:** **[How to finish current activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000787/how-to-finish-current-activity-in-android)**

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

But, this is my suggestion, you should be able to after clicking the `Button`, then clear the activity and restart it(or you can do something like `Gmail` App and doing some stuffs after clicking):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        startActivity(i);
```

Also you can use:

```
Intent m = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(m);
```

Or:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: At least add a few comments to explain what you are doing and why it works. Thank you.